# Angular stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'd like to put some parameters within a link. 
Therefore I use this link:

```
<a ng-switch-when="mp3" ui-sref="recorder.player({path : file.fullPath})">
```

Without referencing the stateParams it works:

```
.state('recorder.player/',{
       url:"/recorder",
       templateUrl:"app/partials/recorder/recorder.html",
       controller: "recorder"
 })
```

With stateParams it don't:

```
.state('recorder.player',{
       url:"/recorder/:path",
       templateUrl:"app/partials/recorder/recorder.html",
       controller: "recorder"
 })
```

Using this I go to the default

```
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home")
```

LogCat says this:

```
10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stateParameter contains a path with "/" ... thats causing a conflict with the route.